# What is batch quota in the context of offline inference (machine learning)?

Tags: tensorflow, hadoop, machine-learning, batch-processing, system-design

The slide below mentions "batch quota". This is from [this video](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/static-vs-dynamic-inference/video-lecture) from [Google's ML Course with TensorFlow](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning).

What do they mean by **"batch quota"**? and why is it an **upside** of an **offline inference** engine?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's just mean to **parallel** or **distributed** algorithm over **N** batches (i.e. **MapReduce**) instead of all dataset sizes. **Offline** as you just predict some large number of data points **locally** rather than **real-time** prediction, so that is the case you have a **larger amount** of data you are trying to predict (ex. **weather data**)

[image: MapReduce]

Comment: Thanks, so what do they mean by quota here? What's the quota in MapReduce?

Comment: You are welcome, In MapReduce quotas means that you are allowed to specify the space and the name of quotas or simply your batch. this term of quotas used in big data and big data frameworks like Hadoop.

Comment: OK, that's a helpful pointers, mostly for completion for this question, if I were to ask you to actually define a "batch quota", what would you say it actually **is**?

Comment: I am going to say it's portion (small part of my needs and i should define resources I have memory size, for example per quota) of my database actually could be a directory contains databases, it's not directly mean dataset (batch) as space quota is a limit on the number of bytes used by files and name could by file name for example. it's run on parallel for prediction process and you are able customize your needs.